# convert to uppercase using macros

Tags: c

I have been given a task to covert lower case character into upper case by using macros .the problem is that i have never been introduced to macros. i just know that its something #define name size .. please can anyone guide me on this issue

Comment: Read a book on C  - there is a list at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: If the homework is on macros, but you have never been "introduced" to macros, what were you doing in class?  Read your course material/lecture notes or wakeup. Thinking that it is `#define <name> <size>` is not going to get you far in this assignment; what you 'know' is wrong.  Also your tutor should probably refrain from giving you homework that simply encourages bad programming technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be something like this:

```
#define LOWERTOUPPER(x) ((x - 'a') + 'A')
```

Then, you would use this function like follows:

```
character = LOWERTOUPPER('z');
```

Which would result in the character variable holding a 'Z'.

Answer (score 8):

The answer above would also change things that aren't letters. Perhaps...

```
#define LOWERTOUPPER(x) (('a' <= (x) && (x) <= 'z') ? ((x - 'a') + 'A') : (x))
```

although that would give trouble if it were invoked as

```
LOWERTOUPPER(*p++);
```

and also wouldn't be right for the EBCDIC character set. All of which goes to prove that this sort of thing is a Bad Idea.